# Webpack's file loader doesn't copy images during production from /src to /dist

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-file-loader

I have a Webpack setup which is split into 2 config files:

`webpack.config.js` handles the development portion which is fired using `npx webpack-dev-server` and `webpack.config.prod.js` respectively which handles the production by typing `npm run build`.

The development config works as expected, but the production one has one problem: everything works fine, but the images aren't copied and optimized from the source folder: `src/images/sm` , `src/images/bg` to `dist/images/sm` , `dist/images/bg`.

webpack.prod.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function(){
  return {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: [
      './src/app.js'
    ],
    watch: true,
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300, // Process all changes which happened in this time into one rebuild
      poll: 1000, // Check for changes every second,
      ignored: /node_modules/,
      // ignored: [
      //   '**/*.scss', '/node_modules/'
      // ]
    },
    devtool: 'source-maps',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      watchContentBase: true,
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      hot: true,
      open: true,
      inline: true,
      port: 9000
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'Webpack starter project',
        template: path.resolve('./src/index.pug')
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
      }),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.pug$/,
          use: ['raw-loader', 'pug-html-loader'],
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            "css-loader",
            "sass-loader"
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|webp)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                outputPath: './images',
                name: "[name].[ext]",
              },
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  };
}
```

webpack.config.prod.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function(){
  return {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: [
      './src/app.js'
    ],
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin()
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'Webpack starter project',
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: path.resolve('./src/index.pug')
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].css',
        chunkFilename: '[id].css'
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
      }),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.pug$/,
          use: ['raw-loader', 'pug-html-loader'],
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            "css-loader",
            "sass-loader"
          ]
        },
        {
         test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|webp)$/,
         use: [
           {
             loader: "file-loader",
             options: {
               outputPath: './images',
               name: "[name].[ext]",
             },
           },
           {
             loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
             options: {
               bypassOnDebug: true,
               mozjpeg: {
                 progressive: false,
                 quality: 45
               },
               // optipng.enabled: false will disable optipng
               optipng: {
                 enabled: true,
               },
               pngquant: {
                 quality: '65-90',
                 speed: 4
               },
               gifsicle: {
                 interlaced: true,
                 optimizationLevel: 3
               },
               // the webp option will enable WEBP
               webp: {
                 quality: 20
               }
             }
           },
         ],
       },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  };
}
```

I uploaded my webpack setup to Google Drive and if anybody wants to check it out, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OkOqc-6hCd5mwIsiFqe4da1O5yrzwWcY/view?usp=sharing) it is.
I googled all day and I don't see anything wrong with my code.
I tried other webpack configs and they have the same code as mine and their images get copied in the dist folder.
Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Somebody on Reddit helped me. All I had to do was import the images in the app.js. Strangely, using other configs never required me to import the images, but I think that's because those configs were built using an older version of file loader.

I also changed the quality property since webpack expects an array instead of a string.

```
pngquant: {
  quality: [0.65, 0.90],
  speed: 4
}
```

To generate images in the dist folder under the same tree scheme as in the src I had to change this part :

```
{
  loader: "file-loader",
    options: {
        name: "[path]/[name].[ext]",
        context: "src"
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with copy-webpack-plugin.
It worked for me.
I tried to like this.

First, you need to install the copy-webpack-plugin module.

> npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev

In webpack.config.js:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports={
 plugins: (
   new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {from: "src/images", to: "images/"}
        ],
      }),
   )
}
```